# How to print limited number of lines having specific field value with awk

Tags: awk, sed, gawk

If I have the file in the following format:

```
a,city1
b,city1
.
.
z,city1
1,city2
2,city2
3,city2
.
.
10,city2
```

Using awk, can I print only `3` records having `city1` and `2` records having `city2`

```
a,city1
b,city1
c,city1
1,city2
2,city2
```

Or can I do it without `awk`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hacky way to demonstrate other features of `awk`

```
$ awk -F, '/city[12]$/ && a[$2]++<4-substr($2,length($2),1)' file
a,city1
b,city1
c,city1
1,city2
2,city2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F, 'BEGIN{n["city1"]=3; n["city2"]=2} ($2 in n) && (c[$2]++<n[$2])' file
a,city1
b,city1
z,city1
1,city2
2,city2
```

I assume you have other 2nd field values than city1 and city2 in your real input, otherwise the solution is even simpler:

```
$ awk -F, 'BEGIN{n["city1"]=3; n["city2"]=2} c[$2]++<n[$2]' file
a,city1
b,city1
z,city1
1,city2
2,city2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

With `grep`

```
$ cat ip.txt 
a,city1
b,city1
c,city1
d,city1
z,city1
1,city2
2,city2
3,city2
4,city2
10,city2

$ grep -m 3 'city1' ip.txt ; grep -m 2 'city2' ip.txt
a,city1
b,city1
c,city1
1,city2
2,city2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.